# Integrating Remember me option to LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

this is my LoginActivity class, i want to do add remember me option to this class.

```
  public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog prgDialog;
// Error Msg TextView Object
TextView errorMsg;
// Email Edit View Object
EditText emailET;
// Passwprd Edit View Object
EditText pwdET;

String email;
// Get Password Edit View Value
String password;
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find Error Msg Text View control by ID
    errorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    // Find Email Edit View control by ID
    emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    // Find Password Edit View control by ID
    pwdET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pwd);
    // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Progress Dialog Text
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    // Set Cancelable as False

    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                // Get Email Edit View Value
                String email = emailET.getText().toString();
                // Get Password Edit View Value
                String password = pwdET.getText().toString();

                // When Email Edit View and Password Edit View have values
                // other than Null
                if (Utility.isNotNull(email) && Utility.isNotNull(password)) {
                    // When Email entered is Valid
                    if (Utility.validate(email)) {

                        new LoginAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this).execute(
                                email, password);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Asynctask started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    }
                    // When Email is invalid
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter valid email",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                // When any of the Edit View control left blank
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please fill the form, don't leave any field blank",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    });

    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {

    private JSONObject responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;
    private Activity activity;

    public LoginAsyncTask(Context context) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
    }

    // async task to accept string array from context array
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        HashMap<String, String> request = null;
        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity requestString = null;
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

        // get the username and password
        Log.i("Email", params[0]);
        Log.i("Password", params[1]);

        try {

            path = "http://192.168.0.xxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/UserAuthentication";
            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // set the API request
            request = new HashMap<String, String>();
            request.put(new String("Email"), params[0]);
            request.put(new String("Password"), params[1]);
            request.entrySet().iterator();

            // Store locations in JSON
            requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
            requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

            // sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Handles the response
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String myResJson;
        try {

            myResJson = responseJson.getString("status");
            String test = myResJson;
            if (test.equals("200")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, ActivityMenu.class);
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, LoginActivity.class);
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   }
  }
```

After some research I was able to come up with this code to do the remember me option using shared preference.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String PREFS_NAME = "mypre";
public static String PREF_EMAIL = "email";
public static String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;

}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // read email and password from SharedPreferences
    getUser();
}

public void doLogin(View view) {
    EditText txtuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
    EditText txtpwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pwd);
    String email = "u";
    String password = "p";
    if (txtuser.getText().toString().equals(email)
            && txtpwd.getText().toString().equals(password)) {
        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_rememberme);
        if (ch.isChecked())
            rememberMe(email, password); // save email and password
        // show logout activity
        showLogout(email);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}

public void getUser() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = pref.getString(PREF_EMAIL, null);
    String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);

    if (email != null || password != null) {
        // directly show logout form
        showLogout(email);
    }
}

public void rememberMe(String user, String password) {
    // save email and password in SharedPreferences
    getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString(PREF_EMAIL, user).putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password)
            .commit();
}

public void showLogout(String email) {
    // display log out activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMenu.class);
    intent.putExtra("user", email);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

 }
```

---

I need help to integrate these 2 classes. I tried but didn't work

this is my out put

```
  public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog prgDialog;
// Error Msg TextView Object
TextView errorMsg;
// Email Edit View Object
EditText emailET;
// Passwprd Edit View Object
EditText pwdET;

String email;
// Get Password Edit View Value
String password;
Button button;
public static String PREFS_NAME = "mypre";
public static String PREF_EMAIL = "email";
public static String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Find Error Msg Text View control by ID
    errorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    // Find Email Edit View control by ID
    emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
    // Find Password Edit View control by ID
    pwdET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pwd);
    // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Progress Dialog Text
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    // Set Cancelable as False

    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                // Get Email Edit View Value
                String email = emailET.getText().toString();
                // Get Password Edit View Value
                String password = pwdET.getText().toString();

                // When Email Edit View and Password Edit View have values
                // other than Null
                if (Utility.isNotNull(email) && Utility.isNotNull(password)) {
                    // When Email entered is Valid
                    if (Utility.validate(email)) {

                        if (emailET.getText().toString().equals(email)
                                && pwdET.getText().toString()
                                        .equals(password)) {
                            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_rememberme);
                            if (ch.isChecked())
                                rememberMe(email, password); // save email
                                                                // and
                                                                // password
                            // show logout activity
                            showLogout(email);

                        }

                        new LoginAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this).execute(
                                email, password);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Asynctask started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    }
                    // When Email is invalid
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter valid email",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                // When any of the Edit View control left blank
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please fill the form, don't leave any field blank",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    });

    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
   }

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // read email and password from SharedPreferences
    getUser();
}

public void getUser() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = pref.getString(PREF_EMAIL, null);
    String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);

    if (email != null || password != null) {
        // directly show logout form
        showLogout(email);
    }
}

public void rememberMe(String user, String password) {
    // save email and password in SharedPreferences
    getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString(PREF_EMAIL, user).putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password)
            .commit();
}

public void showLogout(String email) {
    // display log out activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMenu.class);
    intent.putExtra("user", email);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {

    private JSONObject responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;
    private Activity activity;

    public LoginAsyncTask(Context context) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
    }

    // async task to accept string array from context array
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        HashMap<String, String> request = null;
        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity requestString = null;
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

        // get the email and password
        Log.i("Email", params[0]);
        Log.i("Password", params[1]);

        try {

            path = "http://192.168.0.xxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/UserAuthentication";
            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // set the API request
            request = new HashMap<String, String>();
            request.put(new String("Email"), params[0]);
            request.put(new String("Password"), params[1]);
            request.entrySet().iterator();

            // Store locations in JSON
            requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
            requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

            // sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Handles the response
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String myResJson;
        try {

            myResJson = responseJson.getString("status");
            String test = myResJson;
            if (test.equals("200")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, ActivityMenu.class);
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, LoginActivity.class);
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Who is up-voting this? And **WHY**?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Does it not compile, does it fail, is there a crash? You need to be more specific -- just dumping a  bunch of code just wastes time.

Comment: it loads the menuactivity and then crashes.  Im getting this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.login.ActivityMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @JohnDavid : problem is in `ActivityMenu` Activity instead of `LoginActivity` and you are passing `user` in Intent `showLogout` but not passing `user` in intent when calling `ActivityMenu` from `onPostExecute` probably causing issue

Comment: thanks ρяσѕρєя K, crashing issue got solved.